# Select-String not filtering children items

Tags: powershell

I must be misunderstanding Select-String or piping but why does the following not work.

1. `mkdir testDir`
2. `cd testDir`
3. `ni foo, foobar`
4. `gci . | Select-String -Pattern 'foo'` // returns nothing

I would at least expect it to return `foo` file but it does not

Comment: To answer your question. It doesn't work because the output of `Get-ChildItem` is an object and `Select-String` is meant for that: _"The `Select-String` cmdlet searches for text and text patterns in input strings and files. You can use `Select-String` similar to grep in UNIX or findstr.exe in Windows."_

Comment: Is not meant for that, sorry typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is telling select string to look in the content of files foo and foobar to find strings that match the pattern.  Those two files are empty, hence the result is empty.

The solution is to pass strings containing the Basename of the two files instead of passing the two files.

Try this:

```
gci . | select-object Basename | select-string -pattern 'foo'
```

or this:

```
(gci .).basename | select-string -pattern 'foo'
```

in place of step 4.